# Host a wordpress site in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have a word press website hosted at  for e.g  `http://example.com` in a local language.

Now i want to host another website in English at  `http://example.com/english`

How can i do it .

Please any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create folder called **english** & Install fresh wordpress in that `http://example.com/english`. Create new database and integrate with this new fresh wordpress and you are done.

Your new URL will be :

```
http://example.com/english
```

Your new Admin URL will be :

```
http://example.com/english/wp-admin
```

Comment: No need to create sub domain , you would need to create sub domain only if you want to host like `english.example.com`

Comment: @user3848698 - Any time buddy. Cheers:)

Answer (score 1):

```
->if you are hosting already developed WordPress project on sub domain then.
->create folder under root directory.
->create database and import wordpress database
->change the URL on database name "wp_option" with 'option_name' =>'siteurl' and 'home'. To= http://example.com/english
eg if your domain name http://example.com and you like to create sub domain name 'english' then
url will be http://example.com/english
http://example.com/english/wp-admin`enter code here`

if you are hosting new WordPress project

Create folder called english & Install fresh WordPress in that http://example.com/english. Create new database and integrate with this new fresh WordPress and you are done.

Your new URL will be :

http://example.com/english

Your new Admin URL will be :

http://example.com/english/wp-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

First create sub-domain in your website control penal then install word-press easily.